# PBR painting directly

Tags: texture-painting

Is it possible to use Blender to paint PBR textures?
I mean painting like in specialized programms, where you paint with a setup material over normal map, metallness, roughness and color simultaneously, defining surface look and feel with single stroke.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,Thise is possible using a new branch under developing right now (Not officially).

All you have to do is to create images in the image editor and use them in your nodetree,and you can paint in the viewport of in the image editor.

You can see PBR painting at the end of this [video](https://vimeo.com/151511959)

And you can download the branch from [here](http://www.clement-foucault.com/#blender_pbr).

***Edit for the question in the comments:***

Yes you can in the viewport painting,just check cavity mask and edit the curve to get what you need,
But I love doing it procedurally using nodes and pointiness feature.

[image: Cavity]

Comment: wow! can you also tell if this brush supports features like painting only in cavities or edges?

Comment: @curlybrace I edited the answer.